# Why does first() rxjs operator keep returning array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic2, rxjs

I have a service with a function of type

`getSummary(id: string, universe: string): Observable<INTsummary[]>`

When I call this I only ever want the first item in the `INTsummary[]`, so I'm trying to use rxjs `first` operator to do this:

```
  loadQuickSummary(){
    var obj = this.myService.getSummary(this.user.id, this.user.universe).first();
    console.log("getting quick summary");
    obj.subscribe(r => {
      console.log(`first value ${JSON.stringify(r)}`)
    })
  }
```

from reading docs and stackoverflow, this should return an object, but instead I get back an array of `INTsummary`'s .

How can I get back just the first object in the `INTsummary[]` array?

Comment: `Observable.first` gives you the first value of the *stream* of values, not of the *array* that is one of those values. You need to do that inside a `Observable.map`, where you have that array -> `this.myService.getSummary(...).map(arr => arr[0])...`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `first()` return the first emission for an Observable. So when you have source that emits arrays like `INTsummary[]` then it takes the first array it emits (not the first item in the array).

From your description you want to get the first item in the array so there're are two ways:

```
this.myService.getSummary(this.user.id, this.user.universe)
  .map(array => array[0])
```

... or if you really want to use the `first()` operator:

```
this.myService.getSummary(this.user.id, this.user.universe)
  .concatAll() // flatten the array into separate emission
  .first()
```

Comment: the first works, but when using `.first()` as you mention i get type errors `first does not exist on type INTsummary[]`

Comment: You're just not using it right, `.first()` is a method of `Observable` and `.concatAll()` returns an Observable so the problem is somewhere in your code.

Comment: I have a question, how is concatall better then mergeall?

Comment: @Maximus In this case it'll do exactly the same thing. I'm not sure about the performance however.

Comment: ok, cool, just wanted to understand why you got upvotes and I didnt, I thought maybe you got something better :). And I realize now that the author probably wanted the first item in array, that's how our solutions differ

Answer (score 4):

Right, but the object returned is an array, that what this type states:

```
Observable<INTsummary[]>
```

If it returned plain objects, you would have:

```
Observable<INTsummary>
```

You can use `mergeMap` operator to flatten the array:

```
var obj = this.myService.getSummary(this.user.id, this.user.universe).first().mergeMap(r => r);
```